# I need to fly today, where can I search for options?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airlines, short-notice

A friend of mine needs to fly today. All typical aggregated booking sites don't allow searching for today. Anyone know where it is possible?

Comment: Related: [Last minute flight bookings - better to book online or at the airport?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4213/108)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Kayak](http://www.kayak.com) allows 'today' flight searches. You should also be able to make bookings with airlines on their websites directly.

Comment: but certainly +1 for the recommendation

Comment: LCCs are ALSO available on Kayak, just that most LCCs have their seats sold out way in advance. (For instance in EU, Kayak does both Ryanair and easyJet.)

Comment: Correct! On a later day LCC show in the results. Great site!

Answer (score 8):

Most definitely [Kayak](http://www.kayak.co.uk/) - it's my number one stop for flights, be they a year ahead, or 5 hours from now.  And they certainly support LCCs - I once used Kayak to work out that Miami to London was quite a bit more expensive than Miami to Dusseldorf, and find another way for the final leg.  So I flew to Dusseldorf, trained to Cologne, went into a net cafe, found an EasyJet flight later that day, had lunch and headed to the airport.

It's certainly made travel more flexible for me - thinking back to using travel agents makes me cringe :/

Comment: I love Kayak too, but I've found they do miss some options. I've found flights cheaper on Expedia than Kayak (even though Kayak searches expedia), and I've had flights cheaper than both from travel agents (although I had to really push them to find cheap options).