# Why does the price of air tickets change from one site to another?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

[image]Why does the price of air tickets change from one site to another? (For example, indianeagle.com versus cleartrip.) Sometimes the same flight can have a different price on different sites. Why is this?
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here i was looking for [lowest airfare from New York to India](http://www.indianeagle.com/lowest-airfare-from-newyork-to-india/) i find a big difference in price between indianeagle.com and ClearTrip Look at this snap shoot where you can find a clear difference in price in this sites.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I think your question can be valuable, but at this time it is not really clear. Can you please edit and add more details? Maybe samples/links to sites where you see this happen?

Comment: I have tried to clarify your question. Is this what you meant? If not, please roll it back or edit it further. When replying to me, start your comment with @Fiksdal so that I will get pinged. Also, like Willeke said, it would be good if you could add some examples (screenshots, etc.) of things that you have observed. If we increase the quality of this question, we can have it reopened.

Comment: For mostly the same reasons why the same T-shirt can be sold at different prices in different stores...

Comment: @fkraiem Actually, that's not a very good analogy given the way the airline industry works (see my comments and links under Fiksdal's answer).

Comment: @Relaxed I am aware of all this, but I fail to see how this makes it a bad analogy.

Comment: @fkraiem For the most part, it's not the same t-shirt sold at different prices through different channels, it's a myriad of very simialr t-shirts, available on all channels.

Comment: @Relaxed This has not been my experience. When I search for a flight between the same airports at the same date and time on several sites, the prices I get vary by about 50 euros, tops. This seems to me to be too small a difference to be due to different fare classes. As for the possibility of special arrangements between the producer/manufacturer (here, the airline) and some sellers, this is certainly not limited to the travel industry.

Comment: @fkraiem What's specific about the travel industry is precisely that we are not talking about special arrangements with *some* sellers (that's what your t-shirt analogy would suggest) but something that's available to all, through GDS. Special arrangements are possible too (e.g. with tour operators who package the flight with something else) but that's not what's going on in most cases considered here.

Comment: @JacobWiliams Another major issue is updates: If you are looking at aggregators and search engines, you're never sure that you will actually be able to buy a ticket at the fare posted, it's entirely possible that the fare bucket is already exhausted and if you click through all the links you will either end up with an error or a price very similar to what's posted on other sites.

Comment: The screenshot you've included shows totally different flights. So of course the prices are different. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Fiksdal Sorry for the Mistake now see the screen shot the price of same flights differ in same site and other when i compare it

Comment: @pnuts First Flight ticket is offered by Indian Eagle , Second and Third Flight Tickets are Offered by one Site "ClearTrip" where the price is varies for the same Route and same Flight why???

Comment: @JacobWilliam The flights in the new screenshot are still different.

Comment: @Fiksdal both are Qatar Airways That to route is same in Clear trip (newark-Newyark-Doha-mumbai) but Price is Different

Comment: @JacobWilliam You're asking why different flights on the same site are differently priced?

Answer (score 3):

**Second update in response to second edit:**

The second screenshot you have now included still shows different flights. This alone is "enough said", but in case elaboration is needed:

1. The two examples feature two different routes. One departs from Newark, NY, and the other departs from JFK, NY. The first one has an extra stopover in Chicago (ORD), while the second one doesn't. The domestic US flight is not even operated by Qatar like the rest of the flights, it's operated by American Airlines. I'm sure you understand why all of this can lead to a price difference.
2. The dates on the two sites are different. I'm sure you know that airline ticket prices are different depending on the date.
3. The travel time is different. Even if you ignored point #1 and #2, a different travel time can still make for a different price.

Putting all these points together, you see that you're talking
about two **totally** different products.

It's like asking why a Mercedes sold in one shop has a different price from an Audi sold in another shop.

#### Same exact flight, different site

Now, the following is based on my initial assumption that you were asking "Why would the exact same flight with the exact same airline have a different price at two different sites?" If this was not your intention after all, let me know, and I will remove this from the answer.

The first thing I can think of is that sites you are using to search for flights are often getting a **cut or profit** from the transaction. This profit can vary from site to site. As @fkraiem hinted at in a comment, this is the same with almost any trade.

Some sites forward you the airline's (or even a *fourth* party site) to finish the transaction, whereas others let you pay and finish on their own site. Needless to say, this leads to even more complicated factors determining the rate.

Some sites may also have **special deals** with airlines, affecting prices.

The air ticket market is alive, almost like a stock market. Airlines are constantly playing a game, trying to find a balance between selling a lot of tickets and getting a good price. The prices set by the airlines are ruled by hugely complex, automated computer programs. Human personnel constantly watch the process, adjusting the algorithms and do occasionally intervene manually. These processes involve monitoring and responding to the rates of competitors.  Thus, if they see that a competitor has a special offer going on at a certain site, they may (whether manually, or according to an automated program) decide to also drop their prices on that site (only), in order to try and **compete**. This is just an example. The air ticket market is like a highly competitive game, which has gotten a *lot* more complex in the Internet age.

Another thing is that when you're searching for prices, what you see isn't necessarily what you get. Some sites don't immediately factor in all the **extra fees** that you will have to pay. Some charge quite high *"credit card" fees*. Many people do use credit cards, since they often get travel insurance included that way. Some force the airline to include certain things in the price. Other don't. There are a lot of sites out there. Sometimes a site may seem to have given you a cheaper price, but when you come to the actual booking, you find that your price is higher than initially predicted. On another site, the initial listing may have been closer to the truth.

Comment: That's not exactly how it works. First, the travel industry has arrangements in place for (online) travel agents to get a cut directly from the airline or provider (i.e. they do not charge a fee on top of the listed price, they get a share of the airline's margin. Second, prices are not changed continuously (and certainly not *manually* changed), what's happening is that the airlines publish a myriad of fares with various constraints and limitations.

Comment: A search for a flight between A and B at time XX:XX might therefore be satisfied with different fares and that's the main explanation. While it is superficially the same “product” (although there can be some differences in, e.g. change rules), you are actually buying a different fare. Cheaper fares can become unavailable as they are sold out or the date of the flight nears and some search engines might also fail to find a specific fare combination available on another one.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49412/how-do-airlines-determine-ticket-prices http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/flight-tickets-buy-two-weeks-before-even-during-holiday-seasons and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11501/one-way-versus-return-airfare-tickets

Comment: @Relaxed Your comments are quite comprehensive,  seems like you could move them to an answer. Regarding the cut, this is also what I was trying to say.  It's essentially a profit regardless of how it's done.  Some sites may in fact also charge a fee on top (the credit card fee,  for example.) Regarding automation: Yes,  the fares are mostly automated by complex algorithms.  What I meant by manually is that the airlines have certain departments that constantly work with those algorithms and in some cases,  yes,  manually set the price of a certain ticket.

Comment: @Relaxed I've attempted to clarify the answer. If you see something that is poorly worded, needs clarification or is downright wrong, please let me know. Thanks for the feedback. Also, it does seem like you know enough about this to write your own answer :)

Comment: @Fiksdal here is the snapshot of difference between two sites indianeagle.com and cleartrip for flights from newyork to mumabi[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uP5Oz.jpg

Comment: @JacobWilliam You should edit it into the question itself, along with a small explanation.

Comment: @Fiksdal ls the question is Clear now ??

Comment: Something else to take into account is all the extra fees and charges that airlines and airports attach to tickets, from "fuel surcharges" to "security fees" to "luggage fees" to "checkin fees". Some sites may show all those in the price you see in the initial search (as they're required at least in the EU to do, though not all are compliant even there), many will not show (all of) them.

Comment: @JacobWilliam No, I am actually more confused now. I have updated my answer, though. Please let me know if it answers your questions.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks. A lot of differences to keep track of, lol. What do you mean by metal, btw?

Comment: @pnuts Yeah, the Newark - Chicago flight is probably not operated by Qatar, but by some US airline, right?

Comment: @pnuts Ah, correct.

Comment: @pnuts Haha, yeah. Someone just downvoted both the question and the answer. Maybe they felt this Q was too low quality and shouldn't even have been answered.

Comment: @pnuts You mean more people should have downvoted this if they cared about TSE? I think a lot of people are reluctant to downvote first questions from new users. They want to be welcoming, maybe. This is one of the more friendly sites on SE. A question of similar quality on SO would probably have been received differently.

Comment: @pnuts I was talking more about this (which I totally agree with): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/321647

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44730/discussion-on-answer-by-fiksdal-why-does-the-price-of-air-tickets-change-from-on).