# Does blocking of ticket impacts Air fare?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, fares

As i discussed with travel agent, he was willing to block an international flight ticket with a low fare for 3-4 days.

Now in such cases where ticket is blocked and then released if person decides not to purchase then does it change air fares on various travel portals?

Take a scenario that a last ticket is remaining for cheapest airfare and somebody blocks it. This implies that the fare is not available anymore but if it is released back then same fare will be available again...right?

This can create a situation where one purchases an expensive ticket and next day, a cheap fare becomes available!!

Is this possible?

Comment: Not all the travel agents have access to the same fare buckets, so your scenario already happens every single day when one agent exceeds their own fare bucket limits and another one does not on the same fare construction.

Comment: The bottom line - one purchases an expensive ticket and next day, a cheap fare becomes available - is certainly possible, not just for this reason. Airlines change prices all the time.

Comment: @ugoren: Why would airlines do it? It will lead to issues with people booking earlier having expensive tickets which i believe is unfair.

Comment: @Lokesh, see answers to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49412/how-do-airlines-determine-ticket-prices).