# Why are flights out of Boston cheaper?

Tags: air-travel, price, bos

I was looking at flights out of Baltimore (BWI) to different places; France, Spain, etc. then on one of the bundle sites, it showed the same flight out of Boston (BOS) for less than half the price.

From Baltimore to Paris one month from now is $1200 but from Boston, it's only $448.

I check Philadelphia and other local airports but none were close.

Why are flights out of Boston cheaper?

Comment: Depends where you're going and when and on many other factors.

Comment: A flight from Boston is not "the same" as one from Baltimore. Baltimore has very little international commercial service, so those who value nonstops from BWI will pay a premium for it. Those who value price will connect, or drive to Dulles or Philadelphia.

Comment: See *[How do airlines determine ticket prices?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49412/how-do-airlines-determine-ticket-prices)*. Also of interest is *[Flight tickets: buy two weeks before even during holiday seasons?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/)*

Answer (score 1):

Law of supply.

Probably more people fly from Boston to Europe than from Baltimore (and maybe from Washington, I did not look it up)

Also, you add more distance and more distance costs more fuel and more fuel costs money.

(from googling flight distance from Boston to Paris)

Flight time from Boston to Paris is **6 hours 30 minutes**

Distance from Boston to Paris is **approximately 5540 kilometers**.

(from googling flight distance from Baltimore to Paris)

Flight time from Baltimore to Paris is **9 hours 11 minutes**

Distance from Baltimore to Paris is **approximately 6140 kilometers**.