# Why is it sometimes cheaper to connect via an airport than to finally fly to that airport?

Tags: air-travel, transit, bookings, airlines, price

You can fly from Vienna (**VIE**) to Addis Ababa (**ADD**) for **526€**.

However, flying from Vienna (**VIE**) to Cape Town (**CPT**) connecting through Addis Ababa (ADD) is only **419€**.

So when flying to ADD, it is cheaper to book a flight to Cape Town and not take the connection than to book a flight directly to ADD.

As you can see in the pictures, the 419€ VIE-CPT flights even include the **exact**  526€ VIE-ADD flight.
[image: flight from VIE to ADD]
[image: flight from VIE to CPT over ADD]

### How is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This is quite normal for airfares, and the reason why so-called "[hidden city ticketing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4440)" exists. It's possible because airfares are based on supply and demand, not distance, and there is less competition for a non-stop VIE-ADD flight (only possible on one airline) than for a one-stop VIE-CPT flight (possible on a dozen or more airlines). See Calchas' magisterial answer in *[How do airlines determine ticket prices?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49412)*

Comment: I have also seen that one airline was given rights on one airport based on the number of transfer passengers, besides the number of destination passengers. (I hate it, makes travel harder or more expensive and is even worse for the environment.)

Comment: Self-plug - you can read about why this exists at https://blog.docbert.org/hidden-city-ticketing/