# With FlightHub, How many days in advance should I book a ticket?

Tags: air-travel, budget, tickets, online-resources

So I have a credit with Flighthub.com and I'm trying to find the cheapest deal on a flight to Vegas. I'm not sure when should I book my tickets on FlightHub, cause right now the fare look expensive even if I booking like 60 days in advance!  Since I'm going to Vegas should I book a last minute ticket or 30 days in advance ?

Comment: Pretty sure you'll find this has been asked before.  Booking on Flighthub vs something else doesn't make much difference to the 'rules' - they're just an intermediary.  Have a look at http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7319/is-it-always-wise-to-book-flights-as-soon-as-possible?rq=1 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/flight-tickets-buy-two-weeks-before-even-during-holiday-seasons?lq=1 and more on here ...

Comment: I was wondering if anyone here got a better deals using [FlightHub.com](http://FlightHub.com)  .Sometime agencies might lower their prices

Answer (score 1):

60 days in advance! Since you want to purchase your tickets on FlightHub make sure to compare to price found on your desktop with the mobile version.

Comment: Also you could use the Flight Insight to Las Vegas from Momondo, its a powerful tools

Comment: After my reading I understand that OTAs like FlightHub will change the prices. Kayak and cheapflights are a meta search engine which means all they do is present prices.  but I could see some cached prices of a cached price means the actual price can change a lot from searching to booking. Flighthub seems to be constant with their pricing and they are always the cheapest for my route so I might booked with them.

Comment: Also you could simply [Flighthub](http://plus.google.com/+Flighthub) to check their last minute deals.

Comment: I prefer the [Flighthub](http://www.facebook.com/FlightHubGlobal) Facebook Community