# Have to book a flight in 15 days. Should I wait?

Tags: air-travel, price

I just finalized my itinerary and have to book a flight from Atlanta to Houston on Mar. 16. I found that the price suddenly increased by about $170 on day before and then dropped $30 4hrs ago. Should I keep waiting until Monday or Tuesday?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it always wise to book flights as soon as possible?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7319/is-it-always-wise-to-book-flights-as-soon-as-possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, you should not wait.  [Book a flight as soon as you can](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7319/is-it-always-wise-to-book-flights-as-soon-as-possible?rq=1) if the price now is acceptable.

As a general rule, prices go up as the date of travel approaches, especially if you only have a week or two to go.  Sure, they may go down a bit and you might save a few bucks, but it's much more likely that it will cost you more to wait.

Comment: Plus the risk that you might end up too late.