# Could Delta lower flight cost?

Tags: air-travel, budget, washington-dc

Flight AEX to DCA in May was $388 Sunday, Tuesday $363, today $403.  Will it likely go down again next Tuesday>

Comment: Related: *[Flight tickets: buy two weeks before even during holiday seasons?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2952)*; *[At what time frame is there a significant increase of the price of airplaine tickets?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37445)*; and *[To wait or not to wait](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37141)* among others.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26857/how-do-you-know-if-you-have-found-the-cheapest-air-fare-on-a-given-route

Comment: If I could predict that, I would be rich. Airlines put a lot of effort into making sure that you are unable to buy cheapest except of by coincidence.