# How far in advance should you book a domestic flight within Canada for best value?

Tags: air-travel, budget, canada

Google revealed Cheapair.com articles about how far in advance to book a flight to get a good deal on average ([47 days for US domestic flights](https://www.cheapair.com/blog/travel-tips/when-to-buy-airline-tickets-based-on-1-5-billion-airfares/), [147 days for international flights](https://www.cheapair.com/blog/travel-tips/how-far-in-advance-should-you-book-an-international-flight/)), but are there any better articles specific to Canada?

I read [this website](http://thetyee.ca/Opinion/2012/11/08/Domestic-Flight-Deals/), but its assertion below appears based only on personal experience:

> If I had to pick a "good" time to buy domestic fares within Canada, I'd probably go with about a season ahead (for example, fall sales near the end of summer, or winter sales near the end of fall). Somewhere in the range of eight weeks before departure. It's around this time that it's most common for Air Canada or Westjet to get a little nervous about filling empty seats and perhaps offer a genuine sale. Don't expect miracles though; if you see a "sale" about a six to eight weeks before your departure dates, that's likely the best you'll do. I wouldn't hold out for much longer, because...

Comment: Your almost identical question from Hong Kong to Canada was closed as too broad.  You realise this is likely to happen again? Also we have several questions about booking in advance, have you looked at those?

Comment: @MarkMayo 1. This question should be much narrower and refined? I still do not understand why my earlier question was opined broad (http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3634/please-reopen-how-far-in-advance-should-you-book-a-flight-from-hong-kong-to-can). 2. Yes, but they are not specific to Canada.

Comment: Probably because it used to say Asia, which covers dozens of countries.  Might be worth flagging it to reopen and see what the community says.
Also one of our most popular related questions is VERY specific toCanada in the answer, if you look at it: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/flight-tickets-buy-two-weeks-before-even-during-holiday-seasons

Comment: I am not sure I trust the numbers from CheapAir.com, there are confusing variables at play here. For example, people could be buying more flexible tickets when they book ahead or be more likely to book further ahead for more expensive periods of the year (which their discussion of summer holiday bear out), both of which would increase the average in the early part of the booking window without actually proving that the fares go do down four months before the flight.

Comment: Also, do they even account for differences in price between different routes? I could not see anything about that and if they don't that's another way the data could be biased (imagine for example that people tend to book long-haul tickets a bit earlier or that more people buying a ticket four months out are flexible about dates and destination and thus looking for cheaper fares…). Besides, before the final increase in the weeks running up to the flight date, the differences are really not very big so if I have specific dates/destination, I would still buy ASAP.

Comment: Did you read my link to fivethirtyeight last time? The best answer you will get is "nooone knows, and if somebody did and shared it, it would quickly stop being the best time to buy"