# Do Australian domestic air tickets increase in price close to departure date?

Tags: air-travel, australia, fares, syd, mel

According to Google Flights, there are reasonably priced (~100 USD) tickets from Sydney to Melbourne (roundtrip) for all dates, including a couple of days from now.  Is it typical? I plan to fly in August and I'm trying to work out if I need to buy the tickets now to guarantee a good price, or if I can wait until nearer the date I plan to fly.

---

I don't think this is a duplicate because I'm asking about pricing trends specifically for domestic flights in Australia (because apparently [according to Google Flights] they are different from those in the US).

Comment: We have no way to know what prices will do four months from now, except that generally (but not always) prices rise as the flight date approaches. You must make your own decision.

Comment: I also thought that prices rise as the flight date approaches (as is the case in the US), but even flights departing today are priced around 100 USD. So I was wondering whether it is a normal thing in Australia.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flight tickets: buy two weeks before even during holiday seasons?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/flight-tickets-buy-two-weeks-before-even-during-holiday-seasons)

Comment: In the Northern Hemisphere, especially in Europe, prices during the summer are usually quite high as this is the busiest season with all holidaymakers trying to get to cheap sunny destinations. Not sure how things work out in Australia. It is quite rare for prices to remain stable and much more for them to go down, though. The earlier you book, the better your chances of locking in a good price, unless there are suddenly big sales or competition heats up.

Answer (score 1):

Flight prices, especially those between the major eastern capitals (Sydney, Brisbane, Melbourne), are pretty stable in Australia.

In general there are two pricing tiers used by Australian airlines - the "deals" and the standard.  There's a certain number in the deal bucket and everything else goes into the standard bucket.

If there are available tickets in the cheaper bucket it's worth booking ASAP.  If there's none left the standard flight prices don't tend to increase significantly.  Indeed you'll find prices vary more significantly across the day rather than between days - first thing in the morning is the cheapest.

If you monitor the prices you might get cheaper sale prices if you're flying off peak times (no weeknights, no weekends) but the difference often isn't more than the difference between the "deal" and "standard" options.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, prices for Australian domestic flights tend to increase as the departure date approaches.  You can trivially confirm this with a local booking engine like [Webjet](https://www.webjet.com.au/), and here's a snapshot of their best available SYD-MEL fares for the next few weeks:

[image]

Note how all flights in the next 4 days are >$220, the following 4 are in the $150-200 range, and only beyond that do you see any flights in the sub-$100 range.

Also, there's nothing particularly Australian about this phenomenon, it applies to all modern airline pricing.  See [this epic answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/2967/1893) for much more detail.