# Should I wait until Black Friday for buying my plane tickets for December

Tags: tickets, planning, thanksgiving

I am going to participate in a series of academic events this December in South America. (I myself am from Perú.) The first starts at  December 4 in Santiago (Chile), then I'll be about ten days in Sao Paulo (Brazil), and then I'll be back in Chile for a week, in Concepción.

I plan to travel from Lima to Santiago, then to Sao Paulo, then to Concepción, and finally back to Lima.

I understand it's good policy to buy tickets as early as possible, but also waiting for special days with discounts. The problem is that Black Friday is perhaps too close to the first event date.

Is it too risky for me to wait until the fourth Friday of November to buy my plane tickets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flight tickets: buy two weeks before even during holiday seasons?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/flight-tickets-buy-two-weeks-before-even-during-holiday-seasons)

Comment: Welcome to TSE. The general guidance is to buy plane tickets as soon as you are comfortable with the price, understanding that sometimes they will be higher or lower than the ticket you purchase an hour or a day or a week later. "Black Friday" has almost no bearing whatsoever on airfares, as airlines do not have the same business cycle as retail stores—and I would not think it would be a phenomenon at all outside the United States.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say buy your tickets as soon as you are sure you want to travel on that day.

While sometimes prices drop dramatically, most of the time they drop only a bit and the early buyers are getting better prices.
I have no experience in South America, but as you need to travel to those events, I would not trust there to be cheap tickets.

Answer (score 2):

If the price drops rapidly, it can be risky to wait till less than a week before your flight. After all, you may end up paying even more, but it's your choice.

A good idea is to create price alerts on a few websites like Google Flights and Skyscanner and buy the tickets immediately when the price starts dropping/when you see they are at a reasonable or average price, you don't know what could happen.